# Embedding custom web components in Salesforce CRM

Tags: salesforce, web-component, crm, native-web-component

I'm trying to identify a way to run or embed my custom web components included in Salesforce CRM app. Is it possible to include external script or web component in CRM?

Use case: I've some existing components already built out and want to include within CRM to provide a seamless experience. The components are built and exposed as native HTML web components which can exported either as an npm package or CDN.